# @ConditionalOnBean not work for spring boot test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-context

Hy everyone! I'm trying to solve the problem for a very long time.

There is very simple spring boot test

```
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void testContext() {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

And several beans...

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnBean(CommonService.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SimpleHelper {
...

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConditionalOnBean(CommonFeignClient.class)
public class CommonService {
...

@FeignClient(
    name = "CommonClient",
    url = "localhost:8080"
)
public interface CommonFeignClient {
```

And the main class look as

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients(clients = AnotherFeignClient.class)
public class Application {
```

When the spring application starts everything works ok. SimpleHelper does not created.
But in the spring boot test throw the exception:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleHelper' defined in URL [...]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'foo.bar.CommonService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Please help, I don't understand what's going on anymore =)

Spring boot version is 2.3.0.RELEASE.

Comment: I tried to reproduce issue with above classes. It works for me. Can you share minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `@ConditionalOnBean` correctly, `CommonService` needs to be an auto-configuration class or defined as a bean by an auto-configured class rather than a service that's found by component scanning. This ensures that the bean on which `CommonService` is conditional has been defined before the condition is evaluated. The need for this is described in the [annotation's javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html):

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after.